# Is there a way to report a user who always gives a bad answer?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, users

I got an answer from a user who has nothing but down voted answers. The bad part is the answer given looks ok, but is wrong. Is there a way to report him?

Comment: Downvote it, leave a comment stating that it's wrong and how it's wrong. I don't think it's necessary to do more.

Comment: Know that with enough downvoted answers, the user will eventually, probably, incur the wrath of the [automatic post ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no reason to report that user: he may be a nice person trying to help to the best of his abilities, yet the questions that he attempts to answer are too hard for him at the moment. Downvoting his incorrect answers is the best course of action: eventually he will either "get the message" and research his answers better, or his privilege to post new answers will be suspended until he fixes his old ones.

Comment: Sure he means well, but sometimes just because a person means well isn't justification to "let him go".